# "Sometimes it is the people no one imagines anything of who do the things that no one can imagine" — Alan Turing, into French

Tags: traduction, anglais, citations

J'essaye de traduire cette citation d'Alan Turing tout en gardant le format de "quote" :

> "Sometimes it is the people no one imagines anything of who do the things that no one can imagine" — Alan Turing

Ce que j'ai pu produire est :

> « Parfois, ce sont les personnes dont personne n'imagine quelque chose qui font les choses que personne ne peut imaginer ».

Peut-être que c'est la meilleure façon de la traduire mais j'ai le sentiment que la partie « dont personne n'imagine quelque chose » n'est pas fidèle à ce que voulait exprimer Alan Turing.

Pour vous expliquer pourquoi j'ai l'impression que ça n'est pas fidèle, je pourrais remplacer cette partie par « dont personne n'imagine qu'elles produiraient quelque chose ». Je trouve cette deuxième tournure à la fois plus proche de ce qu'il a voulu exprimer tout en changeant légèrement le sens car ajoutant le verbe produire.

Comment traduiriez-vous ces mots d'Alan Turing tout en gardant le format de citation ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is my take, which I tried to make shorter for greater impact:

> Parfois, ce sont ceux dont on n'imagine rien qui réalisent l'inimaginable.

A little bit of research shows that actually, the movie *Imitation Game* made this quote very popular in France. Below are some of the translations I stumbled upon:

> Parfois les gens dont on n’attend rien font des choses que l’on attendait pas. [[*source*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imitation_Game)]

> Parfois, ce sont les personnes qu'on imagine capables de rien qui font des choses que personne n'aurait imaginées. [[*source*](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjTssTL8J7qAhUuz4UKHSp-D_kQFjAHegQIBxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Frogierfsc.wordpress.com%2F2015%2F04%2F17%2Fparfois-les-gens-dont-on-nattend-rien-font-des-choses-que-lon-attendait-pas%2F&usg=AOvVaw2Md-FntJXSPSwqPCXS_jIG)]

> Parfois ce sont les gens que personne n’aurait imaginé qui accomplissent des choses que personne n’avait imaginé. [[*source*](https://www.kaakook.fr/citation-30645)]

Comment: No need for agreement of the past participle ? (first translation from the end).

Comment: Your take sounds better than the other translations or maybe my understanding of Turing sentence is wrong. What I don't like is that the three other translation seems to be more intending, in my ears, that we are speaking about someone people would regard as "unable to do anything good", but in english then, the negation wouldn't be at the same place, it would rather be "Sometimes it is the people one imagines nothing of do the things that no one can imagine".

Comment: @Dimitris Honestly that one sounds super weird and I only put it to diversify my sources, but I absolutely hate it. :D

Comment: @Reyedy Soit les traductions que nous avons trouvées ont été faites par des robots soit il me faut réviser les règles d'accord du participe passé que j'ai apprises:-)!

Comment: I think https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imitation_Game (using "attendre") best captures the meaning of "the people no one imagines anything of": it's about expectations, not imagination. On the other hand, I find the translation of the second part weaker: "who do the things that no one can imagine" is about doing something amazing, whereas "que l'on attendait pas" is doing something unexpected -- and not necessarily that great -- and therefore it lacks the sense of awe that "que personne n'aurait imaginees" captures better. It's a tough one to translate!

Comment: My 2 cents, as a native speaker: Ce sont parfois ceux dont on n'attendait rien qui arrivent à faire ce que personne n'attendait.

Answer (score 3):

> Parfois ce sont les gens que personne n’aurait imaginés qui accomplissent des choses que personne n’avait imaginées.

Source : [https://www.kaakook.fr/citation-30645#:~:text=Citation%20%2D%20Parfois%20ce%20sont%20les,The%20Imitation%20Game%20%2C%20Alan%20Turing](https://www.kaakook.fr/citation-30645#:%7E:text=Citation%20%2D%20Parfois%20ce%20sont%20les,The%20Imitation%20Game%20%2C%20Alan%20Turing).

> Parfois, ce sont ceux dont on n'attend rien qui font des choses auxquelles nul ne s'attend.

Source : https://lookonthebrightside.skyrock.com/3273797880-Parfois-ce-sont-ceux-dont-on-n-attend-rien-qui-font-des-choses.html

> Parfois, ce sont les personnes qu’on imagine capables de rien qui font des choses que personne n’aurait imaginées

Source : https://lewebpedagogique.com/lacledeslivres/2019/10/30/citation/

Extrait vidéo : [Parfois ce sont les personnes qu'on imagine capable de rien qui font les choses que personne n'aurait imaginées](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u7LomgdEqkk)

**EDIT**

Et une variante d'une locuteur natif (merci @Personne !) :

> Parfois, ce sont les gens que l’on trouve les plus nuls qui se montrent les plus géniaux.

Comment: Parfois, ce sont les gens que l’on trouve les plus nuls qui se montrent les plus géniaux.

Answer (score 2):

> Parfois ce sont les gens dont on n‘attendait rien qui font les choses que personne n‘attendait.

Turing, Einstein et beaucoup de scientifiques sont passés par là. Il ne s'agit pas de se positionner en victime de l'incompréhension des autres mais d'affirmer que quand vous avez confiance en vous-même et que vous sentez que vous êtes sur une bonne voie pour conclure sur un sujet, allez-y et foutez vous de ce que les autres pensent de vous.

Answer (score 0):

You are right in your intuition that « dont personne n'imagine quelque chose » is not an appropriate rendering, but this is so on the count that it is a statement that is much too general, not quite idiomatic. However, the idea you came up with as an afterthought, which results in a form that is correct from the point of view of idiomaticity, introduces a concept not present in the English (production). The following possibility has none of the problems just discussed and could be found to be a satisfying rendering.

- Parfois, ce sont les personnes dont on ne présage rien qui font les choses que personne ne peut imaginer.

You might even go a step further and preserve Turing's parallel conception, at the  small price of rendering the second occurrence of "imagine" by "présager", which is not perfectly accurate.

- Parfois, ce sont les personnes dont on ne présage rien qui font les choses que personne ne peut présager.

Comment: Présage(r) ? Are you sure about that? It is very literal, isn't it?

Comment: Can one use it in this context?

Comment: @Dimitris Je me réfère à la définition suivante du TLFi  : « B. 3. Qqn présage qqc. de qqc. Tirer (une conjecture) de quelque chose. ». Seulement, quelque chose, ce n'est pas quelqu'un et il y aurait peut-être une difficulté.

Comment: @Dimitris Par exemple je crois me rappeler de phrases telles que « Je ne présage rien de bon de son comportement/de son caractère/de sa décision/etc. ». Cependant, le passage de ce qui caractérise une personne à la personne elle-même pourrait ne pas être considéré comme  acceptable; étant porté à réfléchir là-dessus, je vois une difficulté possible et je ne sais pas.